# Why is CORS (localhost) whitelist not working for authentication?

Tags: rest-api, cors

So there are now settings to add domains to the CORS whitelist so they can access the REST API via javascript.  I tried to get this to work using my localhost with an a local ssl so its https://coach.dev:8443

But im still getting this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://coach.dev:8443' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

**UPDATE:**

Also important to note if i request the token via the proxy, and then remove the proxy from all the other requests it does seem to respect the CORS settings and let me do queries without a proxy.

Is is just that the token request wont use the CORS?

Comment: try coach.dev, not localhost

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that localhost is the issue and you can only whitelist domains that are externally hosted. But I have no source to back up my assumption. I seem to recall trying this long before I had even heard of Salesforce and it still being a problem.

Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin). If you're not using Chrome, then it seems more likely to be a Salesforce issue.

Comment: You can whitelist localhost, but it has to be https (I've filed a request that we allow http for localhost only).

Comment: Hey guys, updated the request, had tried with both 127.0.0.1:8443 and coach.dev:8443 adn just mixed up the copy and paste of the error.  I cleaned up above.   I also added an update where it appears the CORS is working correctly for every request besides the token request.  If i use the proxy to get the token then remove it for the query request it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist `https://coach.dev:8443`, since that is the URL that the browser is trying to use. Even if coach.dev resolves to 127.0.0.1, the browser doesn't look at that - it just looks at the host in the URL.

Comment: I did, sorry should have mentioned that.  So an update is that it is working for every request, except the authentication request which gets the token.  Is that just not available without a proxy?

Comment: Correct - authentication endpoints are not available via CORS - see [this comment](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html#comment-1860165250).